# Como redireccionar url duplicadas a url amigable con htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

Estoy teniendo detalles con URL duplicadas, note que esta URL

https://midominio.mx/index.php/intestado-8hykh7gd4?ruta=foro-administrativo/intestado-8hykh7gd4

Manda a la misma pagina, pero esta es la URL amigable

https://midominio.mx/foro-administrativo/intestado-8hykh7gd4

Estoy buscando la forma de configurar el htaccess para que todas las url no amigables sean redireccionadas a las url amigables para que no sean url duplicadas y google no me amoneste, pero no encuentro la forma de como configurar el htaccess.

Este es mi htaccess

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

Para crear las URL amigables uso php, tomo parte de la url donde esta posicionado el usuario y la envio a revisar a la base de datos para ver que exista, si existe trae la informacion y muestra el contenido.

```
$rutas = array();

if(isset($_GET["ruta"])){

    $rutas = explode("/", $_GET["ruta"]);

    $ruta = $rutas[0];

}else{

    $ruta = "inicio";

}

if(isset($_GET["ruta"])){

$rutas = explode("/", $_GET["ruta"]);

if (isset($rutas[1])) {

    $rutas2 = $rutas[1];

}

$item = "ruta";
$valor =  $rutas[0];
$itemN = "ruta";
$valorN =  $rutas2;
$estatus = 1;

/*=============================================
URL'S AMIGABLES DE CONSULTAS EN BD
=============================================*/

$rutaConsulta = ControladorConsultas::ctrMostrarRuta($item, $valor);

if($rutas[0] == $rutaConsulta["ruta"] && $estatus == $rutaConsulta["estatus"]) 
{

    $infoConsulta = $rutas[0];

}

$rutaForo = ControladorFor::ctrMostrarRutaFor($itemN, $valorN);

if($rutas2 == $rutaFor["ruta"] && $estatus == $rutaFor["estatus"]){

    $infoFor = $rutas2;

}

/*=============================================
LISTA BLANCA DE URL'S AMIGABLES
=============================================*/

if($infoConsulta != null){

    include "modules/detalle.php";

}else if($infoFor != null){

    include "modules/administrativo-detalle.php";

}else if(

    $rutas[0] == "verificar"
   ){

include "modules/".$rutas[0].".php";

}else if($rutas[0] == "inicio" ){

        include "modules/inicio.php";

    }else if($rutas[0] == "buscador" ){

            include "modules/buscador.php";

        }else{

    include "modules/error404.php";

}

}else{

include "modules/inicio.php";

}
```

Comment: Si me aceptas un consejo, utiliza la liberia de Symfony para rutas.

Comment: esto esta mal: `RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1` le estas diciendo que acepte y use la url sucia...

Answer (score 0):

esto esta mal: `RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1`

intenta utilizar esto:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @ArcanisGK507 pero al poner el codigo que me pasas solo funciona la raiz, las otras paginas que tengo separadas por ejemplo midominio.mx/foro-1, midominio.mx/foro-2, etc. no funcionan y las paginas con url amigables tambien dejan de funcionar

Comment: @sagitorr ya debe funcionar

Comment: Ya me funciono, ya funcionan todas las paginas, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema, esta url http://midominio/index.php?ruta=esta-es-una-prueba-para-consulta-general me sigue enviando a la consulta real, y lo que estoy buscando es que la anerior url se redireccione a la url amigable http://midominio.mx/esta-es-una-prueba-para-consulta-general pero de forma dinamica para que se aplique para todas las url

Comment: lo que pasa es que ,htaccess no hace redireccionamientos a url... lo que hace es limpiar o cambiar la URL que se muestra en la barra de dirrecion.

Comment: Gracias @ArcanisGK507 estuve pensando en redireccionar la url mala hacia la buena pero con PHP o con tu experiencia que me recomendarias para que ya no cargue la pagina con la url mala?

Comment: @sagitorr es un tema amplio en php puedes crear la regla de tu route; pero necesitas estar claro hasta donde llega el nombre de la pantalla, directorio, archivo php y en donde comienzas a establecer las variables...